# issue in loading data with different

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajaxpost that returns a response in form of json and I want to show the message

```
{ "message" : "100.10.10.100:18080_: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE NoSuchElementException. Please fix it. there might be otehr reason, and need to address it, or call, incorrect username/password-username/port?. " }
```

How can I get the value of json? I used the following but Message is undefined, What are the other ways of getting json object

```
var Message = Obj.response; //Obj.response equals to the json above.
```

Comment: You asked another question about paginations or something, I had typed out a response for you that may have been useful but you deleted the question before I could post it. Please let me know if you are still having trouble with it.

Comment: ah here it is anyway:

I will try give you some psudocode - logic-walkthrough though, put a variable for the amount of pages that can be seen, say 10, the previous and next should always appear(unless there are none in that direction, you can put that code in), now if we know what the current page is, if next page is greater than 10(pagesCanBeSeen) for(i = (pagesCanBeSeen - nextPage); i <= next; i++) print out the number of the page, which is i.

Answer (score 3):

Inside the `onPageClick` function, there should be an `event` as an argument:

```
onPageClick : function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.innerHTML); // should contain the innerHTML of the clicked element, effectivelly the number or 'Previous'
}
```

That is of course, if the function is working as expected.

Other than that, you **wrongly use IDs**. ID can be used only once on a page, if you want multiple elements to share some properties, use classes

```
<li>
    <a class="a-page-item current" ><%= i+1 %></a>
</li>
```

and

```
"click a.a-page-item" : "onPageClick"
```

Also, I consider it better to use `data-*` instead of the proposed `.innerHTML`, unless I am sure, that the values will never change (eg. language mutation, different wording):

```
<li>
    <a class="a-page-item current" data-page="<%= i+1 %>"><%= i+1 %></a>
</li>
```

and

```
console.log($(event.target).data('page')); // same as before, but uses data-attribute
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, your solution logic is briliant man!! I have strill some issues that I am thinking the reason, but I need to ask you sth.  can you tell me event.target.innerHTML is string or number? and can you tell me whats the difference of that with console.log($(event.target).data('page'))

Comment: Both return a `string`, the difference is that innerHTML shows the content of the element, which is what the user sees, while data-attribute is for simplicity (you don't have to worry about the content of the element, of white-spaces, of future changes of language/wording because it can stay the same).

Comment: Thanks Jakub since I want to use: this.collection.setPagination(event.target.innerHTML, 25) is there a way to change it to integer value?

Comment: Sorry my bad. thanks Jakub. Can I ask you sth, maybe by channce you know. Do you know how I can implement previous and next to let the pages go back and forth from the current page? thanks

Comment: If you want previous and next to work, you need to set a global variable eg `currentPage` that you will change on every update and when Previous or Next is clicked, use this variable.

Comment: Can I chat to you Jakob? of course if it do not bother you. or have any email address?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37602/discussion-between-jakub-michalek-and-user2781855)